# GTK can GtkNotebook have a single control and all tabs pointing to it?

Tags: c, user-interface, widget, gtk, swt

I'm an SWT developer. We build SWT on top of GTK.

In swt, some developers like to create a GtkNotebook (TabFolder) with many tabs but all pointing to the same control.

The control is a viewer, and changing tabs changes the content of the viewer.

However, in gtk I haven't been able to make this work. In gtk, it gives me warnings.

Theoretically speaking, can a GtkNotebook have tabs that all point to the same control? (and we just listen to tab-chaning events)?

**[Edit]**
The best I have at the moment is to have tabs be containers, and reparent content into composites upon tab change. Example:
https://bug743889.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=295979

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from creating multiple views for your model? The views should be cheap anyways and you could share some kind of controller to preserve states between the views.

Comment: Personally, I'd go for multiple views. But there is legacy code that uses a single view. One of my recent patches broke the old code and I'm investigating if it's possible to use native GtkNotebook for this purpose or get maintainers to rewrite old code.

Comment: You might use a control like `GtkStackSwitcher` that's not connected to a `GtkStack`.